# How to dismiss fragment in back stack

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I have 3 fragments A, B, C and I replace from A to B and then C
but I need to on backpresed go from C to A. I mean not include fragment B in history stack and here is mode code

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(container, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer that I posted and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Do not add `FragmentTanscation` to BackStack when you change from `Fragment` B to `Fragment` C. So on backPress, you will directly get `Fragment` A.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace fragment A with fragment B, `transaction.addToBackStack(null)` should be added to add A to the stack

But when replacing B with C, don't write `addToBackStack` so B won't be added and you'll be able to navigate back to A when pressing the back button from C

Answer (score 0):

If your code is generic for all your fragments you'll have to write some code to exclude one fragment from being added to the backstack.

Should look something like this

```
private void addFragments() {
    Fragment a = new A();
    Fragment b = new B();
    Fragment c = new C();

    doFragmentTransaction(a, true);
    doFragmentTransaction(b, false);
    doFragmentTransaction(c, true);
}

private void doFragmentTransaction(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackstack) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(container, fragment);

    if (addToBackstack)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code for getting Fragmnet from C to A in onBackpressed method :

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {    

FragmentManager.popBackStack(String name, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
}
```